# Display list of values on JSP using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelandview

I would like to display my List of values in my jsp view, but i am not able to do this.

Here is my controller class below, which is only add List to the `ModelAndView` map and than it redirects to my `index.jsp` page.

**EmployeeController**

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

@RequestMapping(value={"/employee"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listEmployee(){    
    System.out.println("Kontroler EmployeeController");
    LinkedList<String> list = getList();
    ModelAndView map = new ModelAndView("index");
    map.addObject("lists", list);

    return map.getViewName();
}

private LinkedList<String> getList(){
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();

    list.add("Item 1");
    list.add("Item 2");
    list.add("Item 3");

    return list;
}

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Index page</h1>
    <h1>${msg}</h1>
    <a href="/MavenHello/employee">Zaměstnanci</a>
</body>
    <c:if test="${not empty listEmployee}">

    <ul>
        <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${listEmployee}">
            <li>${listValue}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>

</c:if>
```

I am able to access the controller, because every time I hit `"Zaměstnanci"`, the `System.out.println("Kontroler EmployeeController")` prints `"Kontroler EmployeeController"` in to Tomcat Log, but the `index.jsp` page is blank.

Please, can someone give me an advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are populating [`ModelAndView`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) return ModelAndView itself and not [`map.getViewName()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#getViewName--) which return only name of the name without data as stated in docs:

> public String getViewName() Return the view name to be resolved by the
>   DispatcherServlet via a ViewResolver, or null if we are using a View
>   object.

as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/employee" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listEmployee() {
    System.out.println("Kontroler EmployeeController");
    LinkedList<String> list = getList();
    ModelAndView map = new ModelAndView("index");
    map.addObject("lists", list);

    return map;
}
```

Secondly, you are missing jstl tag  `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` on your index page and variable name you given to list is "lists" so iterate over "lists" rather than "listEmployee", as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Index page</h1>
</body>

<c:if test="${not empty lists}">
    <c:forEach items="${lists}" var="lists">
       ${lists}
</c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Also, make sure you have [JSTL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2) dependency in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I updated all files as it is shown in your post above and now everything is working fine. Thanku you :)

Comment: Just wanted to say this answer helped me 3 years later.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `Model` to your controller method params and then add attribute to this model.

```
RequestMapping(value={"/employee"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listEmployee(Model model){    
    System.out.println("Kontroler EmployeeController");
    LinkedList<String> list = getList();
    model.addAttribute("lists", list);

    return "index";
}
```

One more way to do this, is to return `ModelAndView` instead of `String`

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/employee"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listEmployee(){    
    System.out.println("Kontroler EmployeeController");
    LinkedList<String> list = getList();
    ModelAndView map = new ModelAndView("index");
    map.addObject("lists", list);

    return map;
}
```

Just choose which way is better for you.

And also change `listEmployee` in your index page to `lists` as in the `ModelAndView` you have an attribute as `lists` not listEmployee`.

Comment: Well, in the first case i am getting error on retun "index" -> String can not be converted to ModelAndView and in the second case i am getting error 404 on url /MavenHello/WEB-INF/jsp/employee.jsp, well now i am more confused than before :D

Comment: @StepanMocanu sorry, I had a typo. In the first case you should have our method return String. I've changed it already it the answer

Answer (score 0):

Change the key name and try it : `listEmployee --> lists as you are setting it as map.addObject("lists", list);`

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${lists}">
        <li>${listValue}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```