# pass a list of two entity (Students, Course) iterations to a spring view

Tags: java, spring

In a Spring controller, I am performing two iterations of an Entity as shown below : **Students** and **Course** needed to be passed to the view

```
//this is the first iterations
List<Students> searchList = studentService.getAllStudents(splitStr[0]);

    for(Students listItems : searchList){

        String firstname = listItems.getFirstname();
        String lastname = listItems.getLastname(); 

    }
//this is the second iterations
List<Course> courseList = courseService.getAllCourse(splitStr[0]);

        for(Course listItems : searchList2){

            ... 

        }
```

I can only pass one of the list to the view at the moment as shown here

```
return new ModelAndView("searchList", "searchList", searchList);
```

My challenge is to pass this list to the view as well, but I can only return one ModelAndView object

```
return new ModelAndView("searchList", "searchList", courseList);
```

Comment: aModelMap handle represents courseList?

Comment: You can put that in a map to pass them may be and then fetch them accordingly on the other side.

Comment: I see. Then let me take that back and tell you to read the fancy manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42055146/3025545), you can do it like this:

```
ModelAndView mapCourseList = new ModelAndView("searchList");
mapCourseList.addObject("searchList", courseList);

return mapCourseList;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use map:

```
Map<String,Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object();
model.put("courseList", courseList);
model.put("searchList", searchList);

new ModelAndView("theView", model)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do by using below code:

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
public String getLists(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("courseList", courseList);
    model.addAttribute("searchList", searchList);
    return "viewName";
}
```